# how to put data in a graph

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, list, zedgraph

I'm using a graph from ZedGraph. I want to put some data inside it, and I dont know how.
My data comes every 1 minut by a timer, and they are integers. The thing about Zedgraph, is that it has to be double. Thats not the question though. I want the graph to be built every 1 minut, and for every 1 minut, there will be added a new bar in the bargraph. My graph have 6 series. A-F.

```
        DateTime dtime = DateTime.Now;

        int a = ctrscan.analyzeNewScanQuality1A();
        int b = ctrscan.analyzeNewScanQuality1B();
        int c = ctrscan.analyzeNewScanQuality1C();
        int D = ctrscan.analyzeNewScanQuality1D();
        int e = ctrscan.analyzeNewScanQuality1E();
        int f = ctrscan.analyzeNewScanQuality1F();


        double time = Convert.ToDouble(dtime.Minute);

        double[] y = { 90, 100, 95, 35, 80, 35 };
        double[] y2 = { 90, 100, 95, 35, 80, 35 };
        double[] y3 = { 80, 110, 65, 15, 54, 67 };
        double[] y4 = { 120, 125, 100, 40, 105, 75 };
        double[] y5 = { 20, 125, 100, 40, 105, 75 };
        double[] y6 = { 220, 125, 100, 40, 105, 75 };

        double[] x = {time}; 

        BarItem myBar = myPane.AddBar("Quality A", x, y, Color.Red);
```

This graph are only accepting numbers in a list of doubles. As you can see, are every "y" representing one of my A-F. The numbers inside the list, are only random numbers and not for use.

As you can see, i'm getting the numbers in int. I know how to convert, so thats not the question. My question is: How do I get it inside the graph?
I want to put it inside the graph, and after 1 minut, a whole new set of integers will arrive. Then I want the old set, and the new set inside the graph.
The last line are for you to see how i'm controlling my series.

I'm using visual studio c#, and wrinting inside a winform.

Hope you understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       public partial class Chart : Form
{
    public Chart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void SetSize()
    {
        zedGraphControl1.Location = new Point(10, 10);
        // Leave a small margin around the outside of the control

        zedGraphControl1.Size = new Size(ClientRectangle.Width - 20,
                                ClientRectangle.Height - 20);
    }

    private void Chart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateGraph(zedGraphControl1);
        SetSize();
    }

    private void CreateGraph(ZedGraphControl zg1)
    {
        GraphPane myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;
        myPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Date;

        PointPairList PPLa = new PointPairList();
        PointPairList PPLb = new PointPairList();
        PointPairList PPLc = new PointPairList();
        PointPairList PPLd = new PointPairList();
        PointPairList PPLe = new PointPairList();
        PointPairList PPLf = new PointPairList();

        int Max = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < Max; i++)
        {
            DateTime dtime = DateTime.Now;

            //int a = ctrscan.analyzeNewScanQuality1A();
            //int b = ctrscan.analyzeNewScanQuality1B();
            //int c = ctrscan.analyzeNewScanQuality1C();
            //int d = ctrscan.analyzeNewScanQuality1D();
            //int e = ctrscan.analyzeNewScanQuality1E();
            //int f = ctrscan.analyzeNewScanQuality1F();

            int a = 1;
            int b = 1;
            int c = 2;
            int d = 1;
            int e = 3;
            int f = 2;

            double date = (double)new XDate(dtime);

            PPLa.Add(date, (double)a);
            PPLb.Add(date, (double)b);
            PPLc.Add(date, (double)c);
            PPLd.Add(date, (double)d);
            PPLe.Add(date, (double)e);
            PPLf.Add(date, (double)f);

            BarItem myBara = myPane.AddBar("Bar A", PPLa, Color.Red);
            BarItem myBarb = myPane.AddBar("Bar B", PPLb, Color.Blue);
            BarItem myBarc = myPane.AddBar("Bar C", PPLc, Color.Green);
            BarItem myBard = myPane.AddBar("Bar D", PPLd, Color.Black);
            BarItem myBare = myPane.AddBar("Bar E", PPLe, Color.Yellow);
            BarItem myBarf = myPane.AddBar("Bar F", PPLf, Color.Orange);


            zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();

           // sleep(1 minute);

        }
        zg1.AxisChange();
    }

    private void Chart_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetSize();
    }
}
```

refresh your graph every minute, you need to redraw it with the newly added values. you need to get the sleep(1 minute) figured out by yourself.

Chart_load is called when Form1 is loaded

Comment: probably not enough extra stuff added: you got a zedgraphControl added to your form,design?

i made an edit for you with all the stuff i have (even a little sample to show the graph

Comment: So you want me to make this in a new class?? 

And i'm getting a error at:  myPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Date; 
It wants me to write  myPane.XAxis.Type = ZedGrpah.AxisType.Date;

Comment: nr 1: There is no need to make a new class in this example. you can just use a blank form at first, add zedgraphcontrol to your design, make an action when form is loaded, copy past this code inside your form class (maybe rename Chart to form1)

Comment: yes its the name of the chart. when you add a zedgraph from toolbox to your form it names it zedgraphcontrol1 in most first cases

Comment: Ohh now its working. Thanks a lot for your patience with a newbie to coding, but I'm trying to learn, and I'm glad that there are people as you, who takes time and effort to help people as me. Thanks a lot. Now I trying on my own, but if i'm running into future problems, can I then contact you in here?

Comment: just make a new question when finding some mayor errors/questions, this is not a chatprogram!